# How do I build a react-native app using Xcode build

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I created a completely new react-native project using:

```
react-native init demo
```

After the successful creating I can run it using the react-native cli.

```
cd demo && react-native run-ios
```

When I try to open the ios library in Xcode and click on the build button I get the following error:

> Library not found for -lDoubleConversion

Is there a way to build the project using XCode? What could be the reason for my error?

All my packages are updated to the latest versions. (Xcode, react-native, node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **React native** version is `0.59` or later, there may be some problems.

just open the `MyAppName.xcworkspace` instead of `MyAppName.xcodeproj`, and then, building.